# Imputing labels based on a comparison of columns

Tags: r

I don't think this question has been asked on this board before. I have two columns of 1s and 0s in a dataframe. Let's call these columns X and Y, respectively. In a comparison of X and Y for any row, one of four combinations is obviously possible:

- A: 1, 0
- B: 0, 1
- C: 1, 1
- D: 0, 0

Imagine the dataframe has *m* columns total, but we're interested only in X and Y. I'd like to write a function that compares only X and Y and then characterizes the particular combination with the corresponding labels A, B, C, or D in a new column (let's call it Z).

So say the data looks like:

- X Y
- 1 1
- 0 1
- 0 0
- 1 1

The function will ouput:

- X Y Z
- 1 1 C
- 0 1 B
- 0 0 D
- 1 1 C

I imagine this would be trivial but I'm an R newbie. Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a key/value combination unique dataset and then `merge` with the input dataset based on 'X' and 'Y' columns

```
 merge(df1, KeyDat, by = c("X", "Y"), all.x=TRUE)
 #  X Y Z
 #1 0 0 D
 #2 0 1 B
 #3 1 1 C
 #4 1 1 C
```

---

Or to get the output in the same order, use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, keyDat)
#Joining by: c("X", "Y")
#  X Y Z
#1 1 1 C
#2 0 1 B
#3 0 0 D
#4 1 1 C
```

#### data

```
keyDat <- data.frame(X= c(1, 0, 1, 0), Y = c(0, 1, 1, 
     0), Z = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1 <- data.frame(X= c(1, 0, 0, 1), Y=c(1, 1, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. This works perfectly! Can't believe it was as simple as that. Thanks for your help.